# Getting function name from stack frame

Tags: c++, assembly

Suppose I have some functions:

```
void func1 (){
   ...
}

void func2(){
   ...
}

int main(){
func1();

//check called functions

return 0;
}
```

I'd like to check which function was called. Here it is `func1`. I can make one more special checker-function for this. But is it possible to get the name of the function, which was called from stack frame and how?

Comment: No. You might be able to look it up in the debug information, but it's possible it has been stripped by that point. Moreover, the stack frame for `func1` and `func2` will have been destroyed by the time they return to `main` anyway, so you can't get any useful information from them.

Comment: It's possible that the calls to each function are inlined, so I don't believe it would be possible to even get the function name just based on the stack.

Comment: See [backtrace_symbols](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols) for a GNU extension which attempts to do this (within reason). But I might have misunderstood what you wanted ...

Answer (score 1):

By the time the code is compiled, this information is not known anymore.  You can use ad hoc solutions, such as return function name from the function itself (use `__FUNCTION__` macro to make your life easier).  This will be very ugly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not calling the functions directly, but instead use function objects:

```
struct func_base
{
  virtual const std::string& get_function_name(void) const = 0;
  virtual void execute(void) = 0;
  void operator() (void)
  {
    execute();
  }
};
```

This would allow you to retrieve the name of the function that you executed.